# How to use commons-logging api with the latest version of log4j 2

Tags: log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I want to use commons-logging API with log4j 2.

My classes have the following code get the logger ( the commons-logging api )

```
package com.example.testwebapp;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


public class Log4j2ConfigBuilder {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    getLog().debug("DEBUG log entryc 11111 ");
    getLog().info("INFO log entry ");
    getLog().error("ERROR log entry ");
    getLog().warn("#############  WAR log entry ");
  }

  /**
   * @return The logger for the class.
   */
  private static Log getLog() {
    return LogFactory.getLog(Log4j2ConfigBuilder.class);
  }
}
```

I am facing problem, similar to what described in the following question :
[I'm getting "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ReflectionUtil"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700803/im-getting-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-logging-log4j-util-reflectionutil)

So the short question what is the maven dependencies I have to use, to get the commons-logging api work with latest version of log4j2

Following is my non-working pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestWebApp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>2.17.0</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you add the list and versions of your Log4j dependencies? Do you use any JCL replacements (`spring-jcl`, `jcl-over-slf4j`, etc.) or is it vanilla `commons-logging`?

Comment: I have added pom.xml I am using. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Kudos on `<log4j.version>2.17.0</log4j.version>` in your pom.xml.  If you're using log4j, you *MUST* use 2.15 or higher: https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/log4shell-critical-vulnerability-in-apache-log4j/43124/  ALSO: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475146/421195.  You might not need commons logging at all; or you might need to add the adapter (jcl) bridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vanilla Commons Logging has a fixed list of logging implementations it can discover (cf. [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html#Configuration)). Log4j 1.x is among them, but Log4j 2.x is not.

Therefore you need to add the [Log4j Commons Logging Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jcl/index.html) to your classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Under the hood this contains an alternative implementation of [`LogFactory`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html), which will be automatically discovered and used through the [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should consider accepting it (the checkmark sign near the answer). You should do the same in all your other questions, even those you answered yourself.